# In .Net Core, is it possible to lock a bit of code across multiple DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, locking

I have the following setup.

One integration test project with a reference to Lib A.
One application project with a reference also to Lib A.
(Yes, both to Lib A)

The test project cleans&populates(via Lib A) a DB in between tests, and launches&forgets threads of the application.
The application threads do operations (also via Lib A) in that DB.

Therefore, we could have a race condition problem here, for example if test deletes a table, the app creates it, and the test immediatly after tries to create the same table.

Since Lib A is referenced by the 2 projects individually, I can't use a normal static lock to make sure they don't stumble on each other, right? So what can I use?

Comment: For cross-process synchronization you can use a named [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/mutexes).

Comment: Mutex, however its not distributable over different environments. The more distributed way of solving such problems is serializing the actions into a service bus / more queue, or otherwise remote resource that can maintain the consistency for all parties involved

Comment: I strongly suspect that you use "VS projects" as synonym for "OS processes that may or may not run on the same machine"... Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: You might not want to use the same database between the real environment and the tests if you want to perform cleanup after the tests... Also deleting and creating a table in the database is something doesn't look usual..